# How to make tag a clickable

Tags: html, css

```css
.header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.links {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0;
}
.link {
  margin: 0.5em;
}
.network-link {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
 <ul class="links">
  <li class="link"><a href="https://www.google.ru/" class="network-link"><img class="social-link" src="./images/in.svg" alt="linkedIn"></a></li>
  <li class="link"><a href="https://www.google.ru/" class="network-link"><img class="social-link" src="./images/fb.svg" alt="Facebook"></a></li>
  <li class="link"><a href="https://www.google.ru/" class="network-link"><img class="social-link" src="./images/tlg.svg" alt="Telegram"></a></li>
  <li class="link"><a href="https://www.google.ru/" class="network-link"><img class="social-link" src="./images/wapp.svg" alt="Whatsapp"></a></li>
 </ul>
</header>
```

I try to make the navigation menu header but can't make my link clickable. Tag a is wrapped with tag li. I have already found a similar question, so I've added display:block to tag a. However it didn't help. Tell me please how to fix my problem.
Thanks

```css
.header {
  position: absolute;
}
.links {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: .5em;
  margin: 0;
}
.link {
  margin: .5em;
}
.network-link {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: .4em;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
 <nav class="nav">
  <ul class="links">
   <li class="link"><a href="#" class="network-link"><img class="social-link" src="./images/in.svg" alt="linkedIn"></a></li>
   <li class="link"><a href="#" class="network-link"><img class="social-link" src="./images/fb.svg" alt="Facebook"></a></li>
   <li class="link"><a href="#" class="network-link"><img class="social-link" src="./images/tlg.svg" alt="Telegram"></a></li>
   <li class="link"><a href="#" class="network-link"><img class="social-link" src="./images/wapp.svg" alt="Whatsapp"></a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: All 4 of your links are clickable in the snippet you provided (they just don't go anywhere as the hrefs aren't set, but they are clickable). Can you explain in more detail what the problem is, thanks.

Comment: Clickable to do what?

Comment: just change the # in 'href' with an actual url, try reading more about links here => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: when I click on the icon it should link to http://127.0.0.1:5500#/ but there is no effect. I've made cursor:pointer but when I navigate at link my mouse is still default

Comment: the # is used as a dummy url, so it actually clicks but doesn't go anywhere, if you make another html document like test.html, you can put it there as href='test.html', so it will redirect. The # is ONLY used as a default url that doen't redirect but provides all the functions and props of an <a> tag

Comment: actual URL link didn't help as well

Comment: please update the code above so we can see what are you doing =]

Comment: try making a test.html and changing the url to  href='127.0.0.1:5500/test.html'

Comment: I've updated html code

Comment: I think the problem with css because the browser simply doesn't see link

Comment: the code works, and it redirects to google.ru.. not sure what your problem is anymore..
don't use stack overflow fot testing it it will show refuse to connect, try your local !

Comment: Voting to close as the snippet works absolutely fine - the links are seen - and the one answer given appears to have nothing to do with the question as set.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should add the following attributes to the "header" element.

```
.header {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: why? he has a problem with the links "going" somewhere, not with css

Comment: How is this related to the question?

Comment: Thanks, your answer is almost right. The browser didn't see the header, so I changed z-index:1 to z-index:555, and it helped